# LeetCode Reverse Integer (ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' )

Tags: python, algorithm, runtime-error

**Given a signed 32-bit integer x, return x with its digits reversed. If reversing x causes the value to go outside the signed 32-bit integer range [-2**31, 2**31 - 1], then return 0.**

Assume the environment does not allow you to store 64-bit integers (signed or unsigned).

This is my submission

```
class Solution(object):
def reverse(self, x):
    sp= str(abs(x))[::-1].lstrip("0")
    ans= int(sp)
    
    if x > 0 :
        return ans
    else: 
        return -1*ans
```

The int() method should allow me to pass a string value ("12"), but it returns an error saying that it's an invalid literal for int().

The variable **sp** in line 3 is **a str not a float**, so I have no idea why it doesn't run on the leetcode submission page, as it runs ok on VSCode.

Is there any grading guideline that I missed?

And, this is the Value Error I'm getting

[image]

Comment: You are emptying the string before you reverse it, that is `''` is not an `int`. Try `sp = str(abs(x))[::-1]`

Comment: Consider what happens when the value is `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with the original code:  (1) It won't handle zero, and (2) The range checks in the problem description are missing.

For zero, the string representation is `"0"`.  But after calling `lstrip("0")`, it will be the empty string, which `int` won't accept.  This can be fixed by making a special-case check for zero.  An even simpler fix (suggested by Mark) is not to strip the leading zeros.

For the range checks, just add a check to return zero if the value is out of range.

Here's an updated version with both fixes in place.  Note this this version omits the `strip("0")` call, which fixes the zero case:

```
class Solution(object):
    def reverse(self, x):
        sp = str(abs(x))[::-1]
        ans = int(sp)

        if x < 0:
            ans = -ans

        if ans < -2**31 or ans > 2**31 - 1:
            return 0

        return ans
```

This should handle all of the test cases correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Error said you try to int() a None string or letter not number so check variable **sp** before **int()**

Try this

```
class Solution(object):
def reverse(self, x):
    sp= str(abs(x))[::-1].lstrip("0")
    if not sp:
        return 0
    ans= int(sp)
    
    if x > 0 :
        return ans
    else: 
        return -1*ans
```